# How to fix: func selectRow in the TableView does not work when I click Cancel in search bar

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, searchbar

I have a TableView with a playlist of music tracks. When I click on the row, the track starts to play and the current row is selected. Also, I have a search bar, which works fine. But if I click on the row, then on the search bar and then I finally on the Cancel button - the row with the current track is not selected. In other situations, like forward or backward playback, the selection of rows works well.
Simplified, my code looks like this:

```
class TableView: UIViewController, UISearchResaultUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {
   ...
   private var currentSelectedRowIndex = 0
   func ...didSelectRowAt indexPath... {
      ...
      currentSelectedRowIndex = indexPath.row
      print(currentSelectedRowIndex)
   }

   ...
   func searchCancelButtonClicked... {
      print("Cancel button pressed")
      print(currentSelectedRowIndex)
      tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: currentSelectedRowIndex, section 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .middle)
   }
}
```

## //For example, I pressed second row

```
Console message:

1
Cancel button pressed
1
```

==========================

But the row is not selected, what's the problem?

Comment: Hi there. Did you find a solution for this? I have a similar issue on an iOS 12 device. On iOS 15 the row is perfectly selected though.

Comment: *On iOS 13+ the row is perfectly selected.

Comment: I found out what the issue was in my case: I called `tableView.reloadRows(...)` in my `didSelectRowAt` (only on iOS < 12 as a workaround for a layout issue). This call resets the selection state of the reloaded rows. Same applies for `tableView.reloadData()`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `UITableView` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614875-selectrow), it clearly says that calling  `selectRow` does not cause the delegate to receive `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`.

You can move whatever you are doing in `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` to another function and call that function in `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` and `searchCancelButtonClicked`.

Or you can use the following code to manually invoke `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` in `searchCancelButtonClicked`.

```
func searchCancelButtonClicked() {
    print("Cancel button pressed")
    print(currentSelectedRowIndex)
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: currentSelectedRowIndex, section: 0)
    
    yourTableViewOutlet.delegate?.tableView?(yourTableViewOutlet, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
    tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .middle)
}
```

Comment: I do not quite understand you, I just need to select the same row that was selected before I clicked on Search, I saved the index of this row in a variable currentSelectedRowIndex. Why can't I just highlight it?

Comment: That's how `selectRow` works. See the updated answer.

Comment: I tried your code, the track starts playing from the beginning, but the cell is still not highlighted)) This is not as easy as it seems))